# Create different versions of an android application

Tags: android, android-studio

I have build a large project using android studio that contains 4 modules, and now I need to build a new project that use a lot of old project features but with some extra features and with some style difference

so I need to add a new module for my new project where I can easily build and change in the old project or the new project

can anyone advice how to be able to do that in android studio ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Build Variants (aka Build Flavors) which will allow you to have separate src/res folders for each type of your app. More info about Build Variants you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)